# Как выровнять текст в таблице по правому краю с помощью python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

У меня в шаблоне есть таблица с указанным заранее стилем. В нем во второй колонке все выравнивается по правому краю. Но при внесении в него даных стили не работают. 
Фрагмент кода

```
document.tables[0].cell(0, 0).text = title_1  
document.tables[0].cell(0, 1).text = tutor_1
document.tables[0].cell(1, 0).text = title_2
document.tables[0].cell(1, 1).text = tutor_2
document.tables[0].cell(2, 0).text = title_3
document.tables[0].cell(2, 1).text = tutor_3
```

Мне нужно в существующую таблицу, во вторую колонку, записать текст так чтобы он был выровнен по правому краю. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу это сделать? 
[image: То как нужно и как получается]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил все удалив из таблицы начального шаблона текст, который предполагалось заменить. А далее этот код:

```
        cell = document.tables[0].rows[0].cells[1]
        paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
        run = paragraph.add_run()
        run.add_text(tutor_1)
```